# Onsen Cards not showing?

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm trying to use JavaScript to place cards for however many ids there are in a given JSON input, and while the divisions and cards exist in HTML, they don't show in practice. Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

I'm working on a college project, and for that we need to create an app in Cordova. Our team uses Onsen UI as a framework.

EDIT: It seems as though the division "page__background page--material__background" is obstructing my cards. Basically, they're being rendered behind it. I tried z-index in CSS and that didn't do anything. Anyone know how to get these cards to draw on top.

````
        <ons-page id="policies-page">
            <style>
                .intro {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0 20px;
                margin-top: 40px;
                }
                ons-card {
                cursor: pointer;
                color: #333;
                }
                .card__title,
                .card--material__title {
                font-size: 20px;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                var jojo;
                var insertnode1, insertnode2, insertnode3;
                function cardGenerator() {
                    fetch('https://api.thesmokinggnu.net/api/policies')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data=>{
                        console.log(data)
                        // Work with JSON data here
                        jojo = document.getElementById("policies-page");
                        for (policy of data.policies){
                            insertnode2 = document.createElement("DIV");
                            insertnode2.innerHTML = "<ons-card id='policycards' onclick='fn.pushPage({`id`: `policy_read.html`, `title`: `ID: "+policy.id+"`})'>"+policy.policyname+"</ons-card>"
                            jojo.appendChild(insertnode2);
                        }
                    })
                }
                cardGenerator();
                //<ons-card onclick='fn.pushPage({`id`: `policy_read.html`, `title`: `ID: "+policy.id+"`})'>"+policy.policyname+"</ons-card>
            </script>
        </ons-page>
    </template>```

In theory; this code, with the typical JSON input of 6 ids, should output 6 cards with the ID and other information. Instead, no cards. Not even an error.
````

Answer (score 0):

Create `div` inside `ons-page` and add your cards inside this `div`:

```
<ons-page id="policies-page">
 <div id="cards"></div> 
 <style>
   ...
 </style>
 <script>
   var jojo;
   var insertnode1, insertnode2, insertnode3;
   function cardGenerator() {
     fetch('https://api.thesmokinggnu.net/api/policies')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data=>{
       console.log(data)
       // Work with JSON data here
       jojo = document.getElementById("cards");
       for (policy of data.policies){
         insertnode2 = document.createElement("DIV");
         insertnode2.innerHTML = "<ons-card ...</ons-card>"
         jojo.appendChild(insertnode2)
       }
     })
   }
   cardGenerator();
 </script>
</ons-page>
```

Here is a working snippet example:

```js
var jojo;
var insertnode1, insertnode2, insertnode3;
function cardGenerator() {
  let data = {policies:[
    {id:1, policyname: "policyname1"}, 
    {id:2, policyname: "policyname2"},
    {id:3, policyname: "policyname3"}
  ]}
  jojo = document.getElementById("cards");
  for (policy of data.policies){
    insertnode2 = document.createElement("DIV");
    insertnode2.innerHTML = "<ons-card>" + policy.policyname + "</ons-card>"
    jojo.appendChild(insertnode2);
   }
}
cardGenerator();
```

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
ons-card {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
}
.card__title,
.card--material__title {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.js"></script>
 <ons-page id="policies-page">
 <div id='cards'></div>    
 </ons-page>
```

**Why do we need to do so**: when `ons-page` is compiled it has `div`s inside. One of them is `div` with `page__content` class and it seems like we can see only elements inside this `div`. When you append to `ons-page` you append outside of `div.page__content`. That is why we can't see appended elements.